# Can't use java packages while using tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, package, classpath

I'm creating a web-project without IDE and I need to use tomcat 7, so I installed it and I put all the stuffs that I needed for my project in the `tomcat/webapps/` folder.
Since Tomcat need the CLASSPATH set on `servlet-api.jar` I can't use the default CLASSPATH and include my custom packages. There is a way to include tomcat's `servlet-api.jar` inside the project without setting up the CLASSPATH?

In my case I'm using a servlet which needs to connect to a database and so I need to import my database package.
Then if I set the CLASSPATH to `/root/tomcat/webapps/project/src/` my package works, because the database package is inside src, but in this case the servlet can't use tomcat.

If I set the CLASSPATH to `/root/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar` the servlet can connect to tomcat, but the compiler can't find the package because it's not inside the servlet-api.jar.

There's a way out of this deadlock?

Comment: You can set the classpath to both. Just add the delimiter between them

Comment: Thank you very much! I put a : between the CLASSPATH variables and it just worked.

Comment: No problem. Classpath issues are annoying!

Comment: You may choose to delete this question at this point. If not, please click my answer as the solution

Comment: it may be userful for someone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Multiple paths on the classpath, separated by a delimiter.